# Is possible to use std::condition_variable with std::lock_guard?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

I am using a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) combined with a [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) like this.

```
std::mutex a_mutex;
std::condition_variable a_condition_variable;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> a_lock(a_mutex);
a_condition_variable.wait(a_lock, [this] {return something;});
//Do something
a_lock.unlock();
```

It works fine. As I understand, `std::condition_variable` accepts a `std::unique_lock` for it to wait. But, I am trying to combine it with [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) but not able to.

**My question is:** *Is it possible to replace `std::unique_lock` with a `std::lock_guard` instead ?* This can relieve me from manually unlocking the lock every time I use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, a `std::unique_lock` is needed if it is used with `std::condition_variable`. `std::lock_guard` may have less overhead, but it cannot be used with `std::condition_variable`.

But the `std::unique_lock` doesn't need to be manually unlocked, it also unlocks when it goes out of scope, like `std::lock_guard`. So the waiting code could be written as:

```
std::mutex a_mutex;
std::condition_variable a_condition_variable;
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> a_lock(a_mutex);
    a_condition_variable.wait(a_lock, [this] {return something;});
    //Do something
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock

Answer (score 7):

Any call to `wait()` on a condition variable will always need to `lock()` and `unlock()` the underlying `mutex`. Since the wrapper `lock_guard<>` does not provide these functions, it can **never** be used with `wait()`.

Still you could write your own simple mutex wrapper based on `lock_guard<>`, and add the 2 necessary methods. Additionally you would have to use `condition_variable_any`, which accepts any lock/mutex with a lock()/unlock() interface:

```
#include <mutex>

template<typename _mutex_t>
class my_lock_guard
{
public:
    explicit my_lock_guard(_mutex_t & __m) : __mutex(__m)
    { __mutex.lock(); }

    my_lock_guard(_mutex_t & __m, std::adopt_lock_t) : __mutex(__m)
    { } // calling thread owns mutex

    ~my_lock_guard()
    { __mutex.unlock(); }

    void lock()
    { __mutex.lock(); }

    void unlock()
    { __mutex.unlock(); }   

    my_lock_guard(const my_lock_guard &) = delete;
    my_lock_guard& operator=(const my_lock_guard &) = delete;

private:
    _mutex_t &  __mutex;
};
```

And then:

```
#include <condition_variable>
...
std::mutex m;
my_lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m);
std::condition_variable_any cva;
cva.wait(lg, [] { return something;});  
// do something ...
...
```

Comment: I can't seem to get `lock_guard` to work with `condition_variable_any`.  The error message says something about missing member functions `lock()` and `unlock()`.  Why is that?

Comment: Could you add some more details (compiler, error message, code)? Maybe it would also be cleaner to create a new question.

Comment: I used your first code snipped, add includes, `main`, and modified the lambda to just return `true`.  I'm using the latest clang supplied by macOS.  Here are the error messages: http://codepad.org/8Xvh8O1m  Does your code compile for you?  With what compiler?

Comment: Shame on me... In my test code I accidently passed the `mutex` and not the `lock_guard<>` as the parameter to `wait()`... The `wait()` will definitely need to lock and unlock the underlying `mutex`, and since the `lock_guard<>` is so dead simple that it does not even provide these two functions, you will never be able to use it with `wait()`. I changed my answer accordingly. Thanks for this important hint.

Comment: Upvoted for your honest and investigative response.  And I upvoted the other two correct answers as well.

Answer (score 5):

Impossible, but you don’t actually need that.

`std::unique_lock` automatically [unlocks itself in destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/~unique_lock), if it was locked.

Comment: thanks for such a quick clarification. Both answers are acceptable btw. Just chose one of both